# Little angle on flat border

Tags: css

I realy don't know how to describe it. So I've added a couple of pictures to clear it up.
[image]
[image]
I'm making a website for one of my customers, I did not designed the site. The designer added a little angle on the border-top of the active menu item.

The menu item gets a dedicated class.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=border+to+triangle+css+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRteHR6unbAhWJuRQKHRMvChMQrQIIZigEMAM&biw=1600&bih=794

Comment: I'm sorry! Thank you very much!